# Cannot download csv using pyvirtualdisplay + selenium + firefox on Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pythonanywhere, pyvirtualdisplay

I am trying to host my selenium script on Pythonanywhere. 
However, I cannot see any .csv being downloaded through my code. 
I have searched around for a while. such a headache! 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from os import getcwd

with Display():   
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", getcwd())
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv")  
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

    try:    
        browser.get("https://track.cruxsystems.com/login")
        browser.implicitly_wait(30)
        WebDriverWait(browser, 50).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.XPATH, '//button[@uib-tooltip="Download"]')))
        browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@uib-tooltip='Download']")[0].click()
        time.sleep(30)

    finally:
        browser.quit()
        print('finished')
```

I have a screenshot after clicking the download button and it shows the pre-downloading loader and seems like it's about to download the file. However, nothing has been downloaded after.

Comment: As  I can see, this is a login page. Do you have code for login ? Because I can not find nothing with your xpath on the page

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar Ciric, I do have a login set up. I eliminated that part to make my code shorter. I saved a screenshot `browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')`  before downloading and it is exactly what I expect the page should be.

Comment: ok, and do you suceed to find download file. You can open firefox and go to downloads in browser.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-find-and-manage-downloaded-files-firefox

Comment: It's a little hard without being able to view the html for the page, but sometimes you can find the download url for the file. Check around the Button for an `<a href="...">` element, or open up the network tab in your browser and track the request that is used to download the file

Comment: @Brydenr  the download is made by click function in a button element.

Comment: Have you tried setting `browser.download.dir` to something explicit -- say `"/tmp"` -- so that you know exactly where it should be saving the download, and seeing if that works?  It might just be that your current working directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @GilesThomas Yes, I tried /tmp but it does not work either. Right now, I am trying to deploy my script on Lambda AWS instead of Python Anywhere.